# hide() and show() method when a class selector returns 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class selector that is returning 2 elements. I did a `console.log()` and it is an array where 0 is the first and 1 is the second element.

I need to `show()/hide()` these elements depending on a condition.

I tried doing,

```
mySelector[0].hide()
mySelector[0].show()

mySelector[1].hide()
mySelector[1].show()
```

I also tried,

```
mySelector.first().hide()
mySelector.first().show()


mySelector.last().hide()
mySelector.last().show()
```

Both approaches did not work. Also, I understood that even `css()` cant be applied with display: none. What should be my approach to achieve this?

Comment: you're trying to show / hide both elements?  Please show how `myselector` is assigned.

Comment: What is your condition? I mean, do you need to hide both elements or just hide the first and show the second?

Comment: Also, what is your `mySelector`? A `String`? A jQuery object?

Comment: `var mySelector = $(".pre.fileContent")` is my selector

Comment: I have a very long condition (which I'm not supposed to discuss) in a if condition.

Comment: Its a hack for IE8 pre tag problems.. So need to hide and show it depending on a condition.

Comment: you can use $(".pre.fileContent:first").show() or $(".pre.fileContent:last").hide()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following that matches two elements:

```
var mySelector = $(".pre.fileContent")
```

if you want to show (or hide) both:

```
mySelector.show();
```

if you want to show (or hide) one of them:

```
mySelector.eq(n).show();
```

where `n` starts from zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("mySelector:eq(0)").hide();

$("mySelector:eq(1)").show();
```

you can use this

Comment: I doubt it, because you've changed his selector...  his selector variable is a jQuery object, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery method with class name.

for eg.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mySelector"></div>
<div class="mySelector"></div>
<div class="submit">CLICK</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mySelector{border:2px dashed green; height:100px; width:100px;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
    $(".mySelector").toggle(); 
});
```

Live fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4PHV5/)